# Docker Compose with Wordpress app in IPV4 192.168.0.x not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

## Context

Hello community ! Everyone is well?

I have a small WordPress app in local environment builder with docker compose.

I am trying to open work my docker-compose.yml to ipv4 external 192.168.0.x

Today This work only in localhost

- http://localhost
- http://127.0.0.1
- http://0.0.0.0

## Doubt

> Is possible work with external ip wlan ?

Example: http://192.168.0.13 or http://192.168.65.10

This is my docker-compose.yml file bellow (Not working IPV4 wlan IP 192.168.65.10)

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: wordpress-database
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql 
    ports:
      - 3306:3306 
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress-database      
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress-user              
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress-password      
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      internal:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.9.5
      lan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.65.12

  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: wordpress-phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      # PMA_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root-database
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      internal:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.9.4
      lan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.65.11

  wp:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress-app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp-app:/var/www/html     
    ports:
      - 80:80
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress-database        
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress-user            
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress-password    
    depends_on:
      - db
      - pma
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 1.1.1.1
    networks:
      internal:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.9.3
      lan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.65.10

networks:
  internal:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.30.9.0/29
  lan:
    name: lan
    driver: ipvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth0.10
      ipvlan_mode: l2
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "192.168.65.0/24"
          gateway: "192.168.65.1"
```

Source project with wordpress + mysql + phpmyadmin in docker compose
reference: https://gist.github.com/jonathasborges1/592b79245c2b8c686f1cb4b79cf4aff0

I created my file based on this answer : [How can I make docker container IP addresses accessible in a WLAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037085/how-can-i-make-docker-container-ip-addresses-accessible-in-a-wlan/67126254?noredirect=1#comment129184629_67126254)

Answer (score 0):

Problem Resolved, just add project folder to docker shared files

[image]

[image]